# jquery email signup form trying to hide form after submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to use a simple jquery/php newsletter script. The script works fine. As I enter name and email and hit the submit button, it saves data into a .txt file, and display a success message along with the form. Now, I would like to modify the script. I do not want the form to be seen as I hit the submit, instead it should show the success message only "Thank you." Being very novice to javascript, I have so far figured out that I need to "fadeOut" the form after clicking the submit button.

I think the code might be look like

```
      $("#submit").on("click", function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $("#signup").fadeOut(280, function() {
          // callback method to display new text
          // setup other codes here to store the e-mail address
          $(this).after('<p id="success">Thank you</p>');
       });
  });
```

I have tried to integrate this code, but due to my limited JS experience I cannot do it successfully.

Here is my original jquery script

```
var error_1 = "Please enter your valid email address";
var error_2 = "Please enter your  name";
var thankyou = "Thank you";

function trim(str) {
    str = str.replace(/^\s*$/, '');
    return str;
}

function $Npro(field) {
    var element = document.getElementById(field);
    return element;
    return false;
}

function emailvalidation(field, errorMessage) {
    var goodEmail = field.value.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?/);
    apos = field.value.indexOf("@");
    dotpos = field.value.lastIndexOf(".");
    lastpos = field.value.length - 1;
    tldLen = lastpos - dotpos;
    dmLen = dotpos - apos - 1;
    var badEmail = (tldLen < 2 || dmLen < 2 || apos < 1);
    if (!goodEmail || badEmail) {
        $Npro("Error").innerHTML = errorMessage;
        $Npro("Error").style.display = "inline";
        field.focus();
        field.select();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function emptyvalidation(entered, errorMessage) {
    $Npro("Error").innerHTML = "";
    with(entered) {
      if (trim(value) == null || trim(value) == "") { /*alert(errorMessage);*/
         $Npro("Error").innerHTML = errorMessage;
          $Npro("Error").style.display = "inline";
          return false;
      } else {
          return true;
      }
   } //with
} //emptyvalidation

function signup(thisform) {
    with(thisform) {
        if (emailvalidation(email, error_1) == false) {
            email.focus();
            return false;
        };
        if (emptyvalidation(name, error_2) == false) {
            name.focus();
            return false;
        };
    }
    $("#submit, #myResponse").hide(); // Hide the buttom and the message
    $("#loading").show(); // show the loading image.
    params = $("#subform").serialize();
    $.post("optIn.php", params, function(response) {
        //alert(response); //may need to activate this line for debugging.
        $("#loading").hide();
        $("#myResponse").html(thankyou); //Writes the "Thank you" message that comes from optIn.php and styles it.
        $('#myResponse').css({
            display: 'inline',
            color: 'green'
        })
        $("#submit").show();
    })
    return false;
}
```

Here is the html markup

```
<form onSubmit="return signup(this);return false;" method="post" name="subform" id="subform" action="

    <?php echo optIn.php ?>">
    <div>
        <span style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; font-weight:bold;">Subscribe to our newsletter</span>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:20px">
        <div>
           <label style="display: inline-block;width:135px">Email:</label>
           <input type="text"  id="email" name="email" value="">
         </div>
         <div>
           <label style="display: inline-block;width:135px">Name:</label>
           <input type="text"  name="name" id="name"  value="">
         </div>
     <div>
     <div style="display:inline-block;width:135px;">&nbsp;</div>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up">
     </div>
     <div style="width:100%">
       <span id="Error" style="color:red;display:none;"></span>
     </div>
     <div id="myResponse" style="DISPLAY:none;"></div>
       <div id="loading" style="display:none;">
        <img src="wait.gif" alt="">
       </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
//ini_set('display_errors', 0);
header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");

$email  = trim(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["email"]));
$name   = trim(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["name"]));

$pfileName  = "mails.txt";
$MyFile     = fopen($pfileName, "a");
$nline="\"".$email."\"" ."," ."\"".$name."\"" ."\r\n";
fwrite($MyFile, $nline);
fclose($MyFile);
die;
?>
```

Comment: Let me see if I understood. The form fades out but it doesn't show the Sucess message, right?

Comment: @Juan exactly the entire form vanishes out.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing a `.delay()` so that the `fadeOut()` function has finished before attempting to display the success message:

```
  $("#submit").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $("#signup").delay(500).fadeOut(280, function() {
      $(this).after('<p id="success">Thank you</p>');
  });
```

});

Comment: Thanks I'll see if I can set up a test environment later today

Comment: I apologize I haven't had time to fully test your code but I changed part of my answer. Please test and see if it works for you.

Comment: @LarryLane I think you mean to respond to your own answer thread?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want the user to submit the information via your html form.  Then you want the form to go away after you hit the submit button.

From reading the JQuery method you have tried I found one mistake that is preventing your form from fading out. You were using the wrong id for your form in your JQuery code(it should be subform according to your html). Note that I removed your PHP code so that I could create an example in jsfiddle for you.  My sample posts to google.com to prevent your from getting an error page displayed in the results sections.

jsfiddle:  [fade out form on submission](https://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/99w0soLh/)

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(e) {

       //changed from e.stopImmediatePropogation()
       e.preventDefault();

      //#subform is the actual id of your form, you were using signup
      $("#subform").fadeOut(280, function() {
          // callback method to display new text
          // setup other codes here to store the e-mail address
          $(this).after('<p id="success">Thank you</p>');
      });
  });
```

Comment: @Hi Larray, it partially works, since I am using a php script as well. I need to add your code within this function - signup(thisform) {}. Can you suggest something?

Comment: Can you put back in the php code you need an test it

Comment: Do you want to the sign up form to show up again if so place a fade in function  call in the callback function of your post method

Comment: I have just added the php code. Looking forward to hearing your comment.

Comment: @ no, I do not need to show the sign up form again just the success message.

Comment: It is named optIn.php